# Use image as label for itemize

Tags: itemize, includegraphics

While helping a friend with her thesis, I came across a strange issue with itemize. She needs to use some small image as a label for her itemize, and I suggested to use `\item[\includegraphics{xx}]`. However, we discovered that using the optional argument for `\includegraphics` to set some parameter of the figure (i.e. the size) makes the compilation fail.

Instead, if I create an auxiliary command that only takes one argument, the compilation proceeds smoothly.

Can someone give me an hint on why this happens? And maybe on where to look to understand what is happening here? Thank you very much!

Here a MWE, it requires the image `example.png` in your working directory:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\imagebullet}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[\imagebullet{example.png}] This works
        \item[\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example.png}] This does not!
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TeX doesn't track the nesting of brackets as it does for braces.

When you nest braces

```
{.... { .... } ....}
1     2      2     1
```

then TeX knows which pairs belong together.
This doesn't happen for brackets. Here the code simply looks for the next closing bracket. So TeX will pair them like this

```
\item[\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example.png}]
     1                2           1
```

and your command breaks. To avoid this, you can hide the inner bracket in a brace group:

```
\item[{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example.png}}]
     1{                2           2             }1
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you use the same image at all items, it may be easier to modify the `\imagebullet` macro as you wish, then just insert `[\imagebullet]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\imagebullet}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image}}}$}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[\imagebullet] This works
        \item[\imagebullet] This also works 
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image]